# Running a program automatically?

Tags: command-line, xfce, conky

There is a Linux program I like which is Conky, when I run `conky -c mycustomconf.txt` it runs fine.

I want this program to run automatically when I start my computer, without having to type in the command again to start it.

How can I do this?

I am using Ubuntu with Xfce4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add programs that you wish to start up alongside Xfce to your startup items using `xfce4-autostart-editor`, which is accessible at Settings, and then "Xfce 4 Autostarted Applications".

Comment: @MaxMackie `xinitrc` is not environment independent (and Xfce doesn't even read it).

Comment: Really? I always thought that X read the file upon startup (unless told otherwise). Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: @MaxMackie It's passed by certain X startup programs (most notably `startx`) rather than being implicitly read by X itself.